# Why is vb .net repeatedly writing the same line of text in .txt?

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, autocad

I created a .dll file as plugin for AutoCAD. Everytime an event happens it will write in the .txt about it. Why is it repeatedly writing the same line of text in .txt?

```
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices

    Public Class Class1

       <CommandMethod("AddAppEvent")>
       Public Sub AddAppEvent()

           AddHandler Application.SystemVariableChanged, AddressOf appSysVarChanged

    End Sub

    Public Sub appSysVarChanged(ByVal senderObj As Object,
                                ByVal sysVarChEvtArgs As Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.
                                SystemVariableChangedEventArgs)

        Dim oVal As Object = Application.GetSystemVariable(sysVarChEvtArgs.Name)

        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\Users\rita.aguiar\Documents\AutoCAD plug-in\Registo de Eventos.txt", True)
        file.WriteLine("O utilizador " & Environment.UserName & " encerrou o AutoCAD às " & DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm, dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"))
        file.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Example Output in .txt file:

Here it wrote 4 times, sometimes it writes more, others less. Why is this random thing happening? Did anyone have the same problem? I just want it to write once.

O utilizador rita.aguiar encerrou o AutoCAD às 01:11, segunda-feira, 10 setembro 2018

O utilizador rita.aguiar encerrou o AutoCAD às 01:11, segunda-feira, 10 setembro 2018

O utilizador rita.aguiar encerrou o AutoCAD às 01:11, segunda-feira, 10 setembro 2018

O utilizador rita.aguiar encerrou o AutoCAD às 01:11, segunda-feira, 10 setembro 2018

Many thanks.

Comment: Try storing the information about the parameters. Maybe the event is called 4 times for different reasons.

Comment: You need to debug your code. Don't just read it; watch it as it executes.  Set a breakpoint and step through the code.  If you don't know how, do some research on the subject now.  My guess would be that `AddAppEvent` is being called multiple times and thus registering multiple event handlers but that will be easy to spot using the debugger properly.

Comment: I don't get how could the command possibly be called multiple times.
I just load the .dll once and execute the AddAppEvent once.
Also it seems completely random the amount of times it writes the same line in the .txt. Sometimes it just writes once, others it writes like 15!

Comment: If you are monitoring  changes to all system variables, why don't you append the `sysVarChEvtArgs.Name` to your output so that you can see which system variable has changed?

Comment: @TnTinMn, Thank you. that's a great idea.

Comment: It ended up telling me that the system variables are:
RIBBONSTATEO,
VIEWBACKSTATUSO,
PLINEWIDO,
 *ERRNOO.
I don't know how to register this just once, I don't know what are these variables :S Couldn't find them when searching in google

Comment: My guess is that I'm not using the correct system variable for closing autocad. these different variables are hapenning at (aparently) random moments.

Comment: Just an aside... Since streamwriter has a Dispose method, use it or include in a Using block.

Comment: I was following this page: http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20.NET%20Developer's%20Guide/index.html
it's not even right. If I want to register the closing of autocad i need to use the acadBeginQuit Event, not the system variables as it says in that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was following this page: http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20.NET%20Developer's%20Guide/index.html it's not even right. If I want to register the closing of autocad i need to use the acadBeginQuit Event, not the system variables as it says in that page.